# How to use the "Synchronizing CiviCRM data to Custom Posts" plugin (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm upgrading our website and was looking in better ways of integrating CiviCRM with Wordpress. I found a nice plugin called "Synchronizing CiviCRM data to Custom Posts" that might do what I need.

However I installed the plugin and the dependencies, I can create a custom post type via the plugin, I also get the custom fields.. However when I go into the created custom post type there is nothing.

Do I need to setup the fields first via ACF? Just missing a bit of guidance :(.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the plugin you mention, but if you're using ACF you might find that [CiviCRM Profile Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/) works for your needs. It has compatibility with ACF (ideally using the Pro version) as well as front-end form building with [ACF Extended](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-extended/) - although contributions cannot be done via those forms as yet.

Comment: Thnx Christian, will give this plugin a try. There is at least more documentation and information :-).